# Вращение PolygonCollider2D

Tags: c#, unity3d

Столкнулся с проблемой. Суть: создаю двумя кликами объект из префаба. Первым кликом задаю позицию, вторым - в какую сторону его повернуть. Перед объектом рисую прямоугольный коллайдер четырьмя точками, рассчитанными по формуле dX = R * cos(A) и т.д. Так вот, из-за того, что я поворачиваю объект через rotation - у коллайдера начинается свистопляска с положением. Как это грамотно исправить?
Кусок кода в студию:

> ```
>           obj = Instantiate (OBJ) as GameObject;
>           obj2 = Instantiate (OBJ) as GameObject;
>
>           float dX = point2.x - point1.x;
>           float dY = point2.y - point1.y;
>
>           A = Mathf.Atan2(dY, dX);  
>
>           var point_2_position = new Vector2 (7.9f * Mathf.Cos (A + 90f * Mathf.Deg2Rad), 7.9f * Mathf.Sin (A + 90f * Mathf.Deg2Rad)) + point1;
>           var point_1_position = new Vector2 (7.9f * Mathf.Cos (A - 90f * Mathf.Deg2Rad), 7.9f * Mathf.Sin (A - 90f * Mathf.Deg2Rad)) + point1;
>
>           obj.transform.position = point_1_position;
>           obj2.transform.position = point_2_position;
>
>           Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(A * Mathf.Rad2Deg, Vector3.forward);
>
>           var point_1_right = new Vector2 (Mathf.Cos(A - 90f * Mathf.Deg2Rad),  Mathf.Sin(A - 90f * Mathf.Deg2Rad)) + point_1_position;
>           var point_2_right = new Vector2 (23.7f * Mathf.Cos(A), 23.7f * Mathf.Sin(A)) + point_1_right;
>
>           var point_1_left = new Vector2 (Mathf.Cos(A + 90f * Mathf.Deg2Rad), Mathf.Sin(A + 90f * Mathf.Deg2Rad)) + point_2_position;
>           var point_2_right = new Vector2 (23.7f * Mathf.Cos(A), 23.7f * Mathf.Sin(A)) + point_1_left;
>
>
>           line = obj.AddComponent<LineRenderer>();
>           line.SetWidth (0.1f, 0.1f);
>           line.useWorldSpace = true;
>           line.SetVertexCount(2);
>           line.material = materialForLines;
>           line.SetPosition (0, new Vector3 (point_1_right.x, point_1_right.y,  0));
>           line.SetPosition (1, new Vector3 (point_2_right.x, point_2_right.y,  0));
>
>           var line2 = obj2.AddComponent<LineRenderer> ();
>           line2.SetWidth (0.1f, 0.1f);
>           line2.useWorldSpace = true;
>           line2.SetVertexCount(2);
>           line2.material = materialForLines;
>           line2.SetPosition (0, new Vector3 (point_1_left.x, point_1_left.y,  0));
>           line2.SetPosition (1, new Vector3 (point_2_left.x, point_2_left.y,  0));
>
>             pc2d = obj.GetComponent<PolygonCollider2D>();
>
>             Vector2 p1 = (point_1_right - point_1_position) * 2f;
>             Vector2 p2 = (point_1_left - point_1_position) * 2f;
>             Vector2 p3 = (point_2_left - point_1_position) * 2f;
>             Vector2 p4 = (point_2_right - point_1_position) * 2f;
>
>
>             pc2d.points = new[]{p1, p2, p3, p4};
>             pc2d.SetPath (0, new[]{p1, p2, p3, p4});
>
>             obj2.transform.SetParent(obj.transform);
>
>             obj.transform.rotation = rotation;
>             obj2.transform.rotation = obj.transform.rotation;
> ```

Comment: Как вы "рисуете" коллайдер, приведите код, как вы его создаете. Также приведите визуальный пример "спистопляски при вращении".

Comment: А поворот происходит в Update или FixedUpdate?

Comment: Поворот происходит в Update

Answer (score 0):

Для начала нужно понимать что коллайдер напрямую привязан к обьекту. Если ты хочешь **удобно** поворачивать отдельно то нужно сделать коллайдер к дочернему обьекту или к родительскому и обрабатывать его отдельно.

1. Создай пустой обьект, отрисовывай статичный коллайдер и поворачивай только свой дочерний обьект(тот который с Mash-ем). Для чего костыли в виде програмного поворачивания коллайдера?
2. Почему ты создаешь свой коллайдер вручную? Это для оптимизации? Если это 3д обьект, то создай коллайдер в виде куба. Это решит твою проблему без костылей и при этом не создаст никакой особенной дополнительной нагрузки. А еще не нужно будет писать вот эту кучу кода. Если это *оптимизация*, то она **безсмысленная**.
3. попробуй использовать MashCollider если уж это у тебя 3д обьект который ты можешь поворачивать. Вместо ручного создания програмным кодом.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86359/discussion-on-answer-by-andrew--polygoncollider2d).